# Specify v11 (with v11 & v12 installed) Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, version

I am working on a legacy VB.NET application that uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, with Office 2003 installed on the server.

When I publish my site, even though my config file clearly shows v11:

The site will crash saying v12 couldn't be found:
**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

Note: I currently have Office 2003 & 2007 installed on my dev machine, also, when looking @ references I am given the option of selecting v11 or v12 (so v11 is def. there).

Within a page on the site the page does an import statement for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.  Is it possible to specify the version at this point, or any way to force it to use v11 without me uninstalling my v12?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.

Here are the details:

Originally compiled on a system w/ only v12.  Installed v11 and replaced the reference with v11.

Turns out the GAC was still thinking v12.  I flushed it out by deleting the references and then attempting to compile (which of course crashes), then adding the ref. to v11.

So in the end, the issue was just related to the old ref. still existing (even though VS made it seem as though v12 had been removed and v11 had been added).